# Raise exception on update of read only column with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, database-trigger

I'm trying to raise an exception when a read only column is modified. For that I use a trigger before update, but I'm getting syntax errors.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS check_update_guid_line ON line;
CREATE TRIGGER check_update_guid_line
    BEFORE UPDATE ON line FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.guid IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.guid) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'you cant modify the guid of a line');
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "THEN" LINE 29: ...OLD.guid
>   IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.guid) THEN

I guess I could make a procedure extending the code a bunch of lines, but I would like to know why this code doesn't work anyway.

Comment: You can not put the trigger code inline with the create trigger statement. You need to create a function that you can reference. Please see the manual for details and examples: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-EXAMPLES and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split it in two steps, like here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_1()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 COST 1
AS $function$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.id is distinct from OLD.id then
    RAISE EXCEPTION '%','whatever it is';
  END IF;
  return NEW;
END;
$function$
;

CREATE TRIGGER tgr
    BEFORE UPDATE ON line
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_1();
```

Comment: You should use `ist distinct from`  instead of `<>` to handle NULL values properly.

Comment: yes - for some reason I assumed id is PK. Thanks for notice!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is what I ended up doing. Though I find hilarious that I need so much just to execute a single line of code.